# Using FTP with Qt

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qftp

What is right way to use ftp with Qt?
As I see [QFtp](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtftp.git/) is obsolete, last commit is 17 months ago. `QNetworkManager` is very limited and doesn't provide raw command.
I need ftp folder listing, information about file size and certainly uploading and downloading files.

Comment: I can't find it right now but I read multiple times that although you are officially supposed to use `QNetworkAccessManager`, there are some things which do not seem to be possible with it regarding ftp. The consens seems to be to stick to the old `QFtp` module for now.

Comment: Yes it's strange state of affairs. From one side Qt declares `QFtp` as obsolete but from other one doesn't provide any other tool to access `FTP` servers. I've downloaded `QFtp` module to test it with Qt 5.5, may be it still remains usable.

Comment: The biggest project that I am aware of with QFtp is QtWeb.  I did a port of the code to Qt 5.  https://github.com/peteristhegreat/QtWeb

Comment: QFtp has not been modified for a while but is not officially deprecated, maybe it just does not need so much maintenance.